# Formulario con datos por defecto DJANGO

Tags: django, django-forms, djangorestframework

estoy haciendo un formulario en django, pero quiero que este formulario ya tenga algunos datos predeterminados, como podría realiza eso?

ejemplo: quiero que el email ya sea uno por defecto en el formulario.
dejo mi forms:

```
class Meta:
    model = Escuelas
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'email': EmailInput(
            attrs={
                'hidden': False,
                'readonly':True ,
                'required': False
            })}
```

El formulario es algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el views por si acaso

```
def agregarEscuela(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if escuelasForm.is_valid():
            escuelasForm.save()
            return redirect('adminEscuelas')
    else:
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm()
    return render(request, 'administracion/agregar_escuela.html',
                  {'escuelasForm': escuelasForm})
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla es que pases un initial a tu form en tu view agregarEscuela, se hace de esta manera:

```
def agregarEscuela(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if escuelasForm.is_valid():
            escuelasForm.save()
            return redirect('adminEscuelas')
    else:
        initial_data = {'email': 'emailinicial@correo.com', 'nombre': 'nombre por defecto', 'localidad': 'algo'}
        escuelasForm = EscuelasForm(initial=initial_data)
    return render(request, 'administracion/agregar_escuela.html',
                  {'escuelasForm': escuelasForm})
```

El diccionario initial_data debe contener el nombre de los campos junto con su valor inicial.

Se coloca en el else ya que solo quieres que se muestre de manera inicial, cuando cargas el formulario.